# Python MySql.Connector fetchall() is not, in fact, fetching all rows

Tags: python, mysql

This question has been asked a dozen times on this site with no real answer.

I use mysql.connector all the time for work, but recently I've discovered that it does not consistently return all results.

```
sql = ("""SELECT cp.location, cpt.created_ts, cpt.amount FROM 
         customer_plan_transactions cpt
        JOIN customer_plans cp on cp.id = cpt.customer_plan_id
        WHERE cpt.created_ts like "2022-09%" """)

cursor = my_db.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print(len(rows))
```

> 4395

Though, if I run this query through phpMyAdmin:

[image]

Any ideas? Is there another library I should be using for MySql?

edit: It must be a bug with mysql.connector. If I simply re-order the fields in the select statement, I suddenly get all the rows I am expecting.

```
sql = ("""SELECT cpt.created_ts, cp.location, cpt.amount FROM customer_plan_transactions cpt
        JOIN customer_plans cp on cp.id = cpt.customer_plan_id
        WHERE cpt.created_ts between "2022-09-01" and "2022-10-01" """)

cursor = jax_uc.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print(len(rows))
```

> 63140

So, it's a bug, right?

Comment: It might be that python is interpolating `%` in your `sql`. Using string expressions `like` is a rather crude on dates. Alternate:  `cpt.create_ts BETWEEN '2022-09-01' and LAST_DAY('2022-09-01')`

Comment: I've tried to eliminate that as well. The only change I can make that has an effect seems to be to remove two of the 3 fields at the beginning of the query. If I only look for cpt.amount, it returns the whole set of 63140...

Comment: What is the type of the `created_ts` column?